# Django, convert list to JSON preferred method?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm passing an array of data values to Javascript to graph data with Google Charts.

The data structure of the array is really simple, it looks like this:

```
[["Plankton", 725], ["MrKrabs", 681], ["Spongebob", 671]]
```

I'm passing the data from Django to the Javascript file in the template with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">top_voters = {{ top_voters_json|safe }};</script>
<script src="{% static 'spacefinder/index-page-charts.js' %}"></script>
```

which allows index-page-charts.js to access the Array.

I'm curious as to which would be the preferred method of building the list within Django.

Should I be using json.dump to serialize my query-set, or list comprehensions work.

I've implemented both methods, I'd just like to know the pro's and cons of each / which Django developers prefer

I start out with this code, which returns a list of the six top students, sorted by how many ratings they have made.

```
top_voters = Student.objects.annotate(num_ratings=count('rating')).order_by('-num_ratings')[:6]
```

Method 1 (Json.dump):

```
student_list = top_voters.values_list('user__username', 'num_ratings')
top_voters_json = json.dumps(list(student_list), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Method 2 (List-Comp):

```
top_voters_json = [[e.user.username, e.num_ratings] for e in top_student_voters]
```

Which is better / more common (if any), why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is when it's nice that python and Javascript have some similar data structs.

Your list comprehension looks nice, and as a list comprehension it makes it much clearer what the data will look like.

So, if you know that your data will always be `[[int, int],]` then it doesn't matter much. As long as it's only primitives, the result is the same.